# MongoDb: Query over an array of nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've inserted this document into `db.references` collections:

```
{
   "idRef":"asdf-ggtt-001",
   "metadades":[
      {
         "departament":"JUST",
         "changed": ISODate("2016-02-10T10:50:42.389Z")
      },
      {
         "ambit":"AMB1"
      }
   ]
}
```

So, I'd like to get which documents have a `metadades.changed` informed, where `metadades` is an array of nested documents.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies but I didnt quite understand your second last sentence. Are you looking for documents in which the metadates.changed field exists in atleast one of the nested documents?

Comment: Yes, it could be valid.

Comment: what should be the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the full document (parent with nested documents):

```
db.references.find({"metadades.changed": {$exists: 1}}).pretty()
```

This will basically produce all documents with at least one nested document with the changed field present.

If you only want the nested document that matched:

```
db.references.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$metadades"
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        "metadades.changed": {$exists: 1}
    }
},
{
    $replaceRoot: {
        "newRoot": "$metadades"
    }
}
])
```